# iptables block net range

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, redhat

I'm trying to `REJECT` network via `iptables(8)` and for whatever reason it is not doing so:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
# uname -a
Linux X 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 10 17:01:00 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# rpm -q iptables
iptables-1.4.7-14.el6.x86_64
# service iptables restart
iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter          [  OK  ]
iptables: Flushing firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
iptables: Unloading modules:                               [  OK  ]
iptables: Applying firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
iptables: Loading additional modules: nf_conntrack_ftp     [  OK  ]
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:nfs 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:memcache 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:memcache 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:5666 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:snmp 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
# iptables -A INPUT -s 172.16.0.0/16 -j REJECT
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:nfs 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:memcache 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:memcache 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:5666 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:snmp 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
REJECT     all  --  172.16.0.0/16        anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
#
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to block all connections from that network range or just on certain ports?

Comment: I'm trying to block everything, no specific ports.

Comment: The location of the reject rule is more likely your problem. IPTables checks and applies from the top down. As there are allow rules before the Reject, if it matches an Allow first it will succeed. Try `iptables -I 1 INPUT -s 172.16.0.0/26 -j REJECT` This will add it to the top of the list and will block first then allow

Comment: @grag42 You should post your comment as an answer so you can be rewarded with an answer check on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPtables applies rules from the top down in the list. If there are Allow Rules before a Reject, the Allow rules will take precedent.

To block a Network range it needs to be added at the beginning of the IPTables Rules.

`iptables -I INPUT 1 -s 172.16.0.0/16 -j REJECT`

Will insert a Reject rule for the network 172.16.0.0/16 as the fist line in IPtables.

A good [HOW TO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) for IPTABLES.